SVG.js addTo() cannot find target DOM on Svelte
I wanted to add a simple SVG example that is manipulatable with SVG.js
I tried this.
<main>
    <section class="center">
        <h1>Hello!</h1>
        <p>This is project page.</p>
    </section>
    <section id="canvas">
        <canvas></canvas>
    </section>
</main>

<script>
    import { SVG } from '@svgdotjs/svg.js';
    var draw = SVG().addTo("#canvas").size(300, 300)
    var rect = draw.rect(100, 100).attr({ fill: '#f06' })
       
</script>

but it prints out this error on browser console:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'put')
    at Svg.addTo (@svgdotjs_svg__js.js?t=1722923695034&v=5d11dd42:1846:32)
    at instance (index.svelte:13:22)
    at init (chunk-5CD65IUO.js?v=5d11dd42:2137:23)
    at new Project (index.svelte:14:55)
    at createComponent (svelte-hooks.js?v=5d11dd42:206:20)
    at targetCmp.$replace (svelte-hooks.js?v=5d11dd42:269:15)
    at refreshComponent (proxy.js?v=5d11dd42:171:15)
    at ProxyAdapterDom.rerender (proxy-adapter-dom.js?v=5d11dd42:77:5)
    at proxy.js?v=5d11dd42:408:9
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)

It seemed that Svg.addTo() method cannot find the targetDOM.
I thouth it was the problem of DOM load timing, so I tried this:
<main>
    <section class="center">
        <h1>Hello!</h1>
        <p>This is project page.</p>
    </section>
    <section id="canvas">
        <canvas></canvas>
    </section>
</main>

<script>
    import { SVG } from '@svgdotjs/svg.js';

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",()=>{
    var draw = SVG().addTo("#canvas").size(300, 300)
    var rect = draw.rect(100, 100).attr({ fill: '#f06' })
});
</script>

And... nothing happens. No errors, no logs. Seems like 'DOMContentLoaded' event is never fired in svelte? Can anyone help me implementing SVG.js on vite+svelte app?

It's better to use your own action than to use onMount():
<script>
    import { SVG } from '@svgdotjs/svg.js'

    function addSvg(containerElement){
        const draw = SVG().addTo(containerElement).size(300, 300)
        const rect = draw.rect(100, 100).attr({ fill: '#f06' })
    }
</script>

<main>
    <section use:addSvg>
    </section>
</main>


Resolved it:
Svelte has different lifecyle. onMount function does the job of I want.
<main>
    <section class="center">
        <h1>Hello!</h1>
        <p>This is project page.</p>
    </section>
    <section id="canvas">
        <canvas></canvas>
    </section>
</main>

<script>
    import { SVG } from '@svgdotjs/svg.js';
    import {onMount} from 'svelte'

onMount(async()=>{
    var draw = SVG().addTo("#canvas").size(300, 300)
    var rect = draw.rect(100, 100).attr({ fill: '#f06' })
});
</script>


Don't query the DOM for elements when using Svelte, it can potentially lead to elements outside the component being selected. Instead use bind:this on the element or an action as suggested by Peppe L-G, if possible.
